# Div underlapps its siblings

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with a div that underlapps its siblings what breaks the usability.

I'd like to achieve that the content of `#container` starts directly under `header` and that the content gets scrollable immediately when hitting `footer` instead of underlapping `footer`. (To reproduce just add some tasks)

---

For the `header`, I tried to apply some `padding` to `#container` and it kinda works, but breaks when window gets rezized. For the bottom at `footer`, neither `margin` or `padding` worked.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.input = document.getElementById('input');
  window.container = document.getElementById('container');

  window.input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13' && window.input.value != '') {
      addTask();
    }
  });

  /**for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    addTask(i, 'auto');
  }*/
});

const checkButton = () => {
  if (window.input.value != '') {
    addTask();
  }
};

const addTask = (index, type) => {
  let task = document.createElement('div');

  if (!type) {
    task.textContent = window.input.value;
    //localStorage.setItem(window.input.value, window.input.value);
  } else {
    //task.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(index));
  }
  task.classList.add('task');

  let closeButton = document.createElement('div');
  closeButton.textContent = 'X';
  closeButton.classList.add('close');
  closeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeTask(this)');
  task.appendChild(closeButton);

  window.container.appendChild(task);

  window.input.value = '';
};

const removeTask = (task) => {
  window.container.removeChild(task.parentNode);
  //localStorage.removeItem(task.parentNode.textContent.substring(0, task.parentNode.textContent.length - 1));
};
```

```css
#input {
  width: 80%;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

body {
  background-color: #E9FEF2;
}

#container {
  padding-top: 6%; /** My try with the padding */
  width: 100%;
}

h5 {
  margin: 1% 1%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.task {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  background-color: #acaaaa;
  width: 100%;
}

.task:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc7c7;
}

.close {
  text-align: center;
  width: 2%;
  color: #FF0000;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>What's up?</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h5>Your tasks:</h5>
  </header>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <footer>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter task here..." id="input" autofocus>
    <a class="waves waves-light btn" onclick="checkButton()">Add</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I also have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpvQGR?editors=1100) to play around with.

Comment: add `padding-bottom` on body with the same size as if footer height. Or don't position footer absolutely. And use `position: sticky` for header, or just add the padding once again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The issue

The problem is that you are using `position: fixed;` on the `header` and `footer` but don't know how much height they will take up, this means you can't use `margin` or `padding` to reliably "reserve" the space.

## The solution

If `header` and `footer` have a fixed height you could add top and bottom `padding` to `#container` to "clear" them.

If `header` and `footer` don't have a set `height` one way to ensure that they  stay at the top and bottom while the container takes up the remaining space is to use `flexbox` instead.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.input = document.getElementById('input');
  window.container = document.getElementById('container');

  window.input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13' && window.input.value != '') {
      addTask();
    }
  });

  /**for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    addTask(i, 'auto');
  }*/
});

const checkButton = () => {
  if (window.input.value != '') {
    addTask();
  }
};

const addTask = (index, type) => {
  let task = document.createElement('div');

  if (!type) {
    task.textContent = window.input.value;
    //localStorage.setItem(window.input.value, window.input.value);
  } else {
    //task.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(index));
  }
  task.classList.add('task');

  let closeButton = document.createElement('div');
  closeButton.textContent = 'X';
  closeButton.classList.add('close');
  closeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeTask(this)');
  task.appendChild(closeButton);

  window.container.appendChild(task);

  window.input.value = '';
};

const removeTask = (task) => {
  window.container.removeChild(task.parentNode);
  //localStorage.removeItem(task.parentNode.textContent.substring(0, task.parentNode.textContent.length - 1));
};
```

```css
#input {
  width: 80%;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

body {
  background-color: #E9FEF2;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  /*padding-top: 6%;*/ /** My try with the padding */
  width: 100%;    
flex: 1 1 auto;
overflow-y: auto;
}

h5 {
  margin: 1% 1%;
}

header {
  /*position: fixed;
  top: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  /*position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.task {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  background-color: #acaaaa;
  width: 100%;
}

.task:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc7c7;
}

.close {
  text-align: center;
  width: 2%;
  color: #FF0000;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>What's up?</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h5>Your tasks:</h5>
  </header>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <footer>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter task here..." id="input" autofocus>
    <a class="waves waves-light btn" onclick="checkButton()">Add</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is you need to get the height of both `<header>` and `<footer>` during runtime *(because the heights are dynamic)*, this is also needed if you want to be as responsive as possible.

Then after getting the heights, add `padding-top: height of header` and `padding-bottom:height of footer` to the body. Oh, and also remove the `padding-top` in the `#container`

I used JQuery for this, you can convert it to JavaScript if you want.

It still looks like it is still overlapping, but you can immediately scroll after reaching the footer

```js
/*
  You can convert this to javascript if you want
*/

$(function() {
  var headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
  var footerHeight = $('footer').outerHeight();
  $('body').css('padding-top', headerHeight);
  $('body').css('padding-bottom', footerHeight);
});



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.input = document.getElementById('input');
  window.container = document.getElementById('container');

  window.input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13' && window.input.value != '') {
      addTask();
    }
  });

  /**for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    addTask(i, 'auto');
  }*/
});

const checkButton = () => {
  if (window.input.value != '') {
    addTask();
  }
};

const addTask = (index, type) => {
  let task = document.createElement('div');

  if (!type) {
    task.textContent = window.input.value;
    //localStorage.setItem(window.input.value, window.input.value);
  } else {
    //task.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(index));
  }
  task.classList.add('task');

  let closeButton = document.createElement('div');
  closeButton.textContent = 'X';
  closeButton.classList.add('close');
  closeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeTask(this)');
  task.appendChild(closeButton);

  window.container.appendChild(task);

  window.input.value = '';
};

const removeTask = (task) => {
  window.container.removeChild(task.parentNode);
  //localStorage.removeItem(task.parentNode.textContent.substring(0, task.parentNode.textContent.length - 1));
};
```

```css
#input {
  width: 80%;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

body {
  background-color: #E9FEF2;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
}

h5 {
  margin: 1% 1%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.task {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  background-color: #acaaaa;
  width: 100%;
}

.task:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc7c7;
}

.close {
  text-align: center;
  width: 2%;
  color: #FF0000;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <h5>Your tasks:</h5>
  </header>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <footer>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter task here..." id="input" autofocus>
    <a class="waves waves-light btn" onclick="checkButton()">Add</a>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

I have just added Fixed `px` padding to `top` and `bottom` considering your header and footer.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  window.input = document.getElementById('input');
  window.container = document.getElementById('container');

  window.input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13' && window.input.value != '') {
      addTask();
    }
  });

  /**for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    addTask(i, 'auto');
  }*/
});

const checkButton = () => {
  if (window.input.value != '') {
    addTask();
  }
};

const addTask = (index, type) => {
  let task = document.createElement('div');

  if (!type) {
    task.textContent = window.input.value;
    //localStorage.setItem(window.input.value, window.input.value);
  } else {
    //task.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(index));
  }
  task.classList.add('task');

  let closeButton = document.createElement('div');
  closeButton.textContent = 'X';
  closeButton.classList.add('close');
  closeButton.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeTask(this)');
  task.appendChild(closeButton);

  window.container.appendChild(task);

  window.input.value = '';
};

const removeTask = (task) => {
  window.container.removeChild(task.parentNode);
  //localStorage.removeItem(task.parentNode.textContent.substring(0, task.parentNode.textContent.length - 1));
};
```

```css
#input {
  width: 80%;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

body {
  background-color: #E9FEF2;
}

#container {
  padding: 49px 0 71px;
  /** My try with the padding */
  width: 100%;
}

h5 {
  margin: 1% 1%;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #E6E6FA;
}

footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.task {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  background-color: #acaaaa;
  width: 100%;
}

.task:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc7c7;
}

.close {
  text-align: center;
  width: 2%;
  color: #FF0000;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>What's up?</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h5>Your tasks:</h5>
  </header>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <footer>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter task here..." id="input" autofocus>
    <a class="waves waves-light btn" onclick="checkButton()">Add</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this was helpfull.